# List of posts on Tumblr page based on tag

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr, tumblr-themes

I'm an absolute Tumblr novice and am trying to create a list of posts based on a tag.

To clarify I'm NOT trying to simply create a "Tag Page" as I see there are MILLIONS of posts about.  I'm trying to create a custom page within Tumblr that has my own HTML / CSS content and then below that all posts associated with a certain Tag.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look into the documentation here:
https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts

Your API query will look like that:

`api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/posts?api_key={key}&tag={tag}&limit=7`

You need to replace those parameters:

- `{base-hostname}` - The blog you want to query (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#hostname)
- `{key}` - Your API-Key (https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth).
- `{tag}` - Fill in your tag name here.

**Note:** Depending on the programming language you are using, you could use one of the official clients that will do most of the work for you: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#clients

Comment: Hi Alex.  This question got blocked, but could you help me understand the API.  Is that for a feed on an external website or within Timblr?  External right?  I simply want posts to display below some custom HTML on a custom page within Tumblr.

Comment: Do you want to create a special theme? Have a look into this: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/de/custom_themes - here you can write your own HTML and decide how the contents are shown.